# Getting the user's "Last Seen" from a Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

When I chat with a telegram user, I can see for each user their "last seen" - when they last connected to Telegram (even if I haven't chatted with them for a while).

Is there a way to query for this information via the bot [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)? I haven't found a way to access it.

Comment: Do you mean so as to see when they were last online even if they have their privacy setting set to hide such wherein all we see as a result is "last seen recently?"

I'm trying to catch a liar myself and would like to see how to see when the person was last online, but I never can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's currently not possible with the Telegram Bot API.

Comment: It's no longer exact, read my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48506509/3139417

Comment: The questions was targeted at the Telegram Bot API, therefore the answer is still correct.

Answer (score 15):

It's not possible with the Telegram Bot API. 
But it's possible with Telegram API which allows you to build your own customized Telegram clients, and have other methods like read messages, or status (limited by the target users' privacy settings, of course).

After generate an hash to authenticate your API client on [my telegram](https://my.telegram.org/), you can use a library like [Telegram-MTProto](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto) to call [contacts.getStatuses](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getStatuses) which return an array of [ContactStatus](https://core.telegram.org/type/ContactStatus) and know if user is online or offline.

```js
const getStatuses = async () => {
    const statuses = await telegram('contacts.getStatuses', {})
    // Check online status
    if(statuses[0].status._ === 'userStatusOnline')
        // Online
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
About this telegram API, do they have some documentation for Python or can you point towards Python tutorials of Telegram API, I want to use this getStatuses, but can't get it right

Answer (score -1):

In plus messenger , using bot login , relative last seen is shown.

Maybe you could ask them in their Official support group: https://t.me/plusmsgrchat (I'm blocked)

Answer (score -2):

https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans

> Bots have no online status and **no last seen timestamps**, the interface shows the label ‘bot’ instead.

Comment: That's not really what I asked - not how to get the status of a bot, but how, as a bot, to get the "last seen" of the human I'm interacting with.